# Uploading a image file to a collection

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have a quick question regarding the process of uploading an image to a collection inside of mongoDB. I have a collection of candidates like this 
`{name: "",role: "", support: "" }` and i was wondering if its possible to an an image to the collection like this  `{name: "",role: "", support: "", image:""}`. Im asking purely because most information online usually points to Gridfs and it uses its own collections fs.file and fs.chunk.

It is possbile to add the image file to the collection or will I have to reference fs.file instead? I am hoping I can just add the image file as I can alter the Schema I created for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend referencing the image name or source as a pointer to the actual image origin. I use Amazon Web Services S3, which is a managed object storage service. In mongodb store a pointer the image location within the object store referred to as a "bucket" within the S3 service. Your use case was a bit unclear, but I hope this helps as it may be more cost effective and performance efficient rather than to actually store an image in your database.